# Android: How to set a stop flag in native C thread from Java

Tags: android, multithreading

In my NDK Android app, Java part runs native C code to perform intensive calculations. It does so by creating an AsyncTask worker object that runs the native code in a separate thread via the JNI. The Java GUI has a stop button and the native code has a variable which is used as a stop flag to abort a lengthy calculation.

How do I set the stop flag in the native code, running in a separate thread, when the stop button is pressed in the main GUI thread?

Comment: Just kill the thread?

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to do it safely so that all memory used by the native code is de-allocated before stopping the thread that is running it.

Comment: you use signal handlers for that. Look up what signals threads get when they are killed, and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks I'll look up signals. I actually found the solution to the problem in my case, which was just to set up a JNI function that sets the stop flag in the native code. This JNI function is called from the main UI thread upon pressing the stop button in the Android app. When the stop flag is set, the native code knows how to free memory and return, resulting in the thread being safely concluded.